# Is going on a pre-marriage 'stag' problematic

Tags: marriage, parties-celebrations, hukot-hagoyim

Assuming that the activities and setting (etc.) are considered kosher, is there a problem of 'not going in their ways' (or other related issue) by attending a stag party for a man who is getting married? (The same question is extended to a 'hen party' for women)

Comment: It is just the general Jewish custom to hold them on the Shabbos before ...

Comment: If all the activities and the setting is kosher it wouldn't really be called a 'stag' party.